# Derived table query not working in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

The following query results in an error.

```
select monstart,
       sum(datediff(least(m.monend, t.end_date) + interval 1 day,
                    greatest(m.monstart, t.start_date)
                   )
           ) as days_worked
from travel t join
     (select date('2016-01-01') as monstart, date('2016-01-31') as monend union all
      select date('2016-02-01') as monstart, date('2016-02-29') as monend union all
 select date('2016-03-01') as monstart, date('2016-03-31') as monend union all
 select date('2016-04-01') as monstart, date('2016-04-30') as monend union all
 select date('2016-05-01') as monstart, date('2016-05-31') as monend union all
 select date('2016-06-01') as monstart, date('2016-06-30') as monend union all
 select date('2016-07-01') as monstart, date('2016-07-31') as monend union all
 select date('2016-08-01') as monstart, date('2016-08-31') as monend union all
 select date('2016-09-01') as monstart, date('2016-09-30') as monend union all
 select date('2016-10-01') as monstart, date('2016-10-31') as monend union all
 select date('2016-11-01') as monstart, date('2016-11-30') as monend union all
 select date('2016-12-01') as monstart, date('2016-12-31') as monend union all
     ) m
     on t.end_date >= m.monstart and t.start_date <= m.monend
group by m.monstart;
```

The error is as follows.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') m
     on t.end_date >= m.monstart and t.start_date <= m.monend
group by m.mon' at line 19
```

Comment: It looks like a rather convoluted query btw

Comment: Indirectly. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra `union all` at the end. Just remove it.

```
select monstart,
       sum(datediff(least(m.monend, t.end_date) + interval 1 day,
                    greatest(m.monstart, t.start_date)
                   )
           ) as days_worked
from travel t join
     (select date('2016-01-01') as monstart, date('2016-01-31') as monend union all
      select date('2016-02-01') as monstart, date('2016-02-29') as monend union all
 select date('2016-03-01') as monstart, date('2016-03-31') as monend union all
 select date('2016-04-01') as monstart, date('2016-04-30') as monend union all
 select date('2016-05-01') as monstart, date('2016-05-31') as monend union all
 select date('2016-06-01') as monstart, date('2016-06-30') as monend union all
 select date('2016-07-01') as monstart, date('2016-07-31') as monend union all
 select date('2016-08-01') as monstart, date('2016-08-31') as monend union all
 select date('2016-09-01') as monstart, date('2016-09-30') as monend union all
 select date('2016-10-01') as monstart, date('2016-10-31') as monend union all
 select date('2016-11-01') as monstart, date('2016-11-30') as monend union all
 select date('2016-12-01') as monstart, date('2016-12-31') as monend -- removed a union all from here
     ) m
     on t.end_date >= m.monstart and t.start_date <= m.monend
group by m.monstart;
```

Answer (score 1):

you should do it. as follow:

```
  select monstart,
           sum(datediff(least(m.monend, t.end_date) + interval 1 day,
                        greatest(m.monstart, t.start_date)
                       )
               ) as days_worked
    from travel t join
         (select date('2016-01-01') as monstart, date('2016-01-31') as monend union all
          select date('2016-02-01') as monstart, date('2016-02-29') as monend union all
     select date('2016-03-01') as monstart, date('2016-03-31') as monend union all
     select date('2016-04-01') as monstart, date('2016-04-30') as monend union all
     select date('2016-05-01') as monstart, date('2016-05-31') as monend union all
     select date('2016-06-01') as monstart, date('2016-06-30') as monend union all
     select date('2016-07-01') as monstart, date('2016-07-31') as monend union all
     select date('2016-08-01') as monstart, date('2016-08-31') as monend union all
     select date('2016-09-01') as monstart, date('2016-09-30') as monend union all
     select date('2016-10-01') as monstart, date('2016-10-31') as monend union all
     select date('2016-11-01') as monstart, date('2016-11-30') as monend union all
     select date('2016-12-01') as monstart, date('2016-12-31') as monend 
         ) m
         on t.end_date >= m.monstart and t.start_date <= m.monend
    group by m.monstart;
```

Answer (score 1):

You simplify the query and remove the join pseudo table with something like this:

```
select 
    sum(datediff(least(monend, end_date) + interval 1 day,greatest(monstart, start_date))) as `days_worked`,
    (adddate(last_day(start_date), 1) - interval 1 month) as `monstart`,
    last_day(start_date) as `monend`
from travel
group by `monstart`,`monend`
```

This will work in any year without having to update your query.

**EDIT - Try this instead:**

```
select 
    (adddate(last_day(start_date), 1) - interval 1 month) as `monstart`,
    last_day(start_date) as `monend`,
    sum(
        datediff(
            least(last_day(start_date), end_date) + interval 1 day,
            greatest((adddate(last_day(start_date), 1) - interval 1 month), start_date))
    ) as `days_worked`
from travel
group by `monstart`,`monend`
```

Comment: getting this error ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'm.monend' in 'field list'

Comment: I managed to fix the error and your query seems to be right. Thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry about that. I forgot to remove the table aliases. I've updated the code example.

Comment: even this query doesn't work. "ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'monend' in 'field list'
"

Comment: Also the query results seems t be different from the other answer's results

Comment: If you are getting the error, you should not be getting results. If you are getting results (your second comment), how are they different? I can see that the first column could cause the error, since it refers to other calculated columns. Basically, I should have replaced monend and monstart in the first calculation with the formulas in the respective columns.

Comment: I've edited the answer with the corrected code so that it doesn't refer to the calculated date columns. I also changed the column order to more closely match the original query.